# Why does application close on back button - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

As my question says, pressing phone back button application is going back to custom splash screen rather than previous page. Any idea what would be the issue ? Following is main.dart code

```
void main() => runApp(new MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.red),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: SplashScreen(),
    ))
```

Splash screen closes after 3 seconds and app goes to login page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your SplashScreen page code

Comment: after 3 seconds it goes to Login Page
`@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    Timer(
        Duration(seconds: 3),
        () => Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => LoginApp())));
  }`

Comment: @AR I had added splashscreen page code.

Comment: What you want to do exactly, do you want close application directly from the login screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you incorrectly use navigator, use `pushReplacement` to replace `SplashScreen` with a new one. and use `push` to open a new screen on top of the previous.

example:

```dart
// Close splash screen and open MainPage
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MainPage.route());

// Open LoginPage on top of the previous page
Navigator.of(context).push(LoginPage.route());
```